# How to sort a list of objects?

Tags: java, list, sorting, date

I have a list of objects that I want to sort according to their "date" attribute. Each object has a Date attribute which specifies its age. How can I sort these objects from the newest to the oldest? I heard of `Comparator` but I don't know if it applies to dates.

Can somebody help me figure out how to do that?

Comment: It does. Your comparator should simply take two dates and return appropriate values if one is before the other

Comment: Date myDate1 = new Date(); Date myDate2 = new Date(); myDate1.compare(myDate2) will return a value between -1 and 1 to indicate with one if for the other or if they are equals (0).

Comment: the accepted answer for the duplicated question addresses this exact case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various methods of before(), after(), compareTo(), or convert the value into a Long and then compare that instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date into `timestamp` and sort it. It is very easy for sorting.